# How to NOT select div's which have empty title or have not? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tryed construction like this:

```
$('div[title!=""]')
```

but div's with no title are also in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty `title` :

```
$('div[title=""]')
```

Not empty `title` with `:not` selector:

```
$('div:not([title=""])')
```

Not empty `title` with `not()` method:

```
 $('div').not('[title=""]')
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v265Lfbe/)

Comment: You might as well show the [`not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) as well (it's not worth another answer just for that).

Comment: i hate stackoverflow... answered first, but noone cares.

Comment: You may also want to try this: `$('div[title]').filter(function(){return this.getAttribute('title')!='';});`

Comment: please note that your solution selects divs with no title at all as not empty title! this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[title]').css('background','green'); // if has title attr
$('div[title=""]').css('background','blue'); // if has empty title or has no title attr
$('div:not([title])').css('background','red'); // if has no title attr
$('div[title]:not([title=""])').css('background','yellow'); // if has title but not empty
```

[CHECK LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/1cuh5xk3/1/)

PS. Last one in example overwrites the first one (changes the background from green to yellow). Just try to comment out all lines except one, and see what happens. Second line overwrites one from first aswell.

Comment: I need exactly that, but in reverse